# git ignore doesn't ignore already submitted files?

Tags: java, git, github

This is my .gitignore file:

```
src/main/resources/*
!src/main/resources/input
```

In the past i submitted a few files under `resources` folder.

Now I see some files are still monitored by git (as changed)
even if they are under `src/main/resources/foo1`

how come the git ignore don't hide these files from the `git status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gitignore` governs only addition of new files, files that are already tracked continue to be tracked.

To remove them from Git but keep them in filesystem, use `--cached` option of `rm`:

```
git rm -r --cached src/main/resources
```

Answer (score 0):

git (and other vcs) ignore only new files. If you already added file which should not be in a repository it is better to delete it.